# How to filter remove null values in spark python

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, spark-streaming, aws-glue

I'm trying to filter out the null values in a column and count if its greater than 1.

`badRows = df.filter($"_corrupt_record".isNotNull)  if badRows.count > 0: logger.error("throwing bad rows exception...") schema_mismatch_exception(None, "cdc", item )`

I'm getting a syntax error. Also tried to check using :

`badRows = df.filter(col("_corrupt_record").isNotNull),` 
`badRows = df.filter(None, col("_corrupt_record")),`
`badRows = df.filter("_corrupt_record isNotnull")`

What is the correct way to filter out if there is data in the _corrupt_record column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, e.g.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
...
df.where(F.col("colname").isNotNull()) 
...
```

Many of the options you provide are not the right syntax as you note.